# Left simple submodule and right simple submodule

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\mathbb{C}$ be complex field. Then groupring $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is a left $\mathbb{C}[G]-$ module as well. Let $M$ be a left simple submodule of $\mathbb{C}[G]$. I believe that $M$ is also a right simple submodule. How can I prove that $M$ is also a right simple submodule. i.e. $m\cdot g \in M~\forall ~m \in M, g \in G$ and that it has no proper non zero right submodules. This is  trivially true for abelian groups but how to approach in general.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. ${\mathbb C}[G]$ is a direct sum of two sided ideals, each of which is a full matrix algebra over ${\mathbb C}$. The left submodules of these ideals are the columns  of the matrices, whereas the right submodules are the rows.

Comment: @Derek Holt I am considering $\mathbb{C}[G]$ as module over itself. Isn't (left\right) module same as (left\right) ideal in that case?

Comment: @caleb Yes left/right submodule is the same as left/right ideal, respectively. But left ideal is not the same as right ideal as I thought I explained in my comment.

Comment: Take a look at for example [this old answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3375593/11619). Probably the same calculation was done earlier on our site, but that was the first hit the search engine gave me. Anyway, in there a four-dimensional two-sided ideal of $\Bbb{C}[S_3]$ is described. I invite you to write that ideal as a sum of two 2-dimensional left submodules as well as two 2-dimensional right submodules. Then you will see that none of the 2-dimensional summands are both left and right submodules.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen for $\mathbb{C[S_3]}$, I computed two 2 dimensional left modules as $\mathbb{C[e-(12)+(23)-(123),(12)-(13)+(123)-(132)]}$ and $\mathbb{C[e+(12)-(23)-(132),(23)-(13)-(123)+(132)]}$. They are not right modules. Similarly I computed two 2 dimensional right modules. They are also simple. Can you explain why it is enough to study only left modules. Why simple right modules will give representations similar to that of given by one of the simple left modules?

Comment: If $G$ is a finite group and $V$ is a left module with action $g\cdot x, g\in G, x\in V$, then we can turn $V$ into a right module $V_r$ by defining $x\star g:=(g^{-1})\cdot x$. The process can obviously be reversed. Therefore this change does not give us much new. You will see that the character of $V_r$ is the complex conjugate of the character of $V$ (also afforded by the dual left module $V^*$).

Comment: That worked because the mapping $g\mapsto g^{-1}$ extends  linearly to anti-isomorphism of the group algebra. Have you heard of *opposite rings*?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, so group ring $(\mathbb{C}[G],+,\cdot)$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{C}[G],+,\diamond)$ where $x \diamond y = y\cdot x$. Correct?